# php First value of array not displaying

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following bit of code and for some reason in the first WHILE loop the first value of $actor_list (when $i = 0) does not display.  If I simply echo $actor_list[0] then it displays fine, but in the loop it will not display.  I merely get [td][/td] as the output.  The remaining values of the array display fine.

Also the line

```
echo '</tr><tr> </br>';
```

is not displaying.

What am I missing here?  The value of $num_actors is an even number in my test scenario so there doesn't seem to be a reason for the above echo line to be skipped.

```
$actor_list = explode(" ", $actors);
$num_actors = count($actor_list);

if ($num_actors <= 6) {
foreach ($actor_list as $actor) {
    echo '[td]'.$actor.'[/td] </br>';
}
} elseif ($num_actors <= 12) {
    if ($num_actors % 2 == 0) {
        $half_actors = $num_actors / 2;
        while ($i <= ($half_actors - 1)) {
            echo '[td]'.$actor_list[$i].'[/td] </br>';
            $i++;
        }
        echo '</tr><tr> </br>';
        while ($i <= $num_actors) {
            echo '[td]'.$actor_list[$i].'[/td] </br>';
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the $i variable to 0 at some point?

Comment: @JuanAntonioDelgado has it... on your first iteration `$i` hasnt been defined so its not `0`... throw in `$i = 0;` right after `$half_actors = $num_actors/2;` You'll also need to reset it to `0` just before your second `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I did anything with php...I had $i == 0 so once I changed that to $i = 0 that part worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not initialising the variable `$i` to 0, which means it will be set to 'null' and thus not reference the 0th index of the array; but when it's then incremented its value will become 1.

> **Note:** [..] Decrementing **NULL** values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Try adding:

```
$i = 0;
```

before the `if` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  I initialized $i elsewhere, but I moved it down to the loop area.  It didn't make a difference though, that first value still isn't displaying.

Comment: Hmm.. You mentioned that `echo '</tr><tr> </br>';` wasn't displaying - can I asked have you correctly included the opening and closing tags for each of those table rows as well?

Comment: Oh great I've just seen your comment above, easy mistake to make!

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes.
This is working for me.
Try it out.

```
<?php
$actor_list = 'act1 act2 act3 act4 act5 act6';
$actors = explode(" ", $actor_list);
$num_actors = count($actor_list);

//debug
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($actor_list);
//echo "</pre>";

echo "<table>";
if ($num_actors <= 6) {
    foreach ($actors as $actor) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$actor.'</td></tr>';
    }
} elseif ($num_actors <= 12) {
    if ($num_actors % 2 == 0) {
        $half_actors = $num_actors / 2;
        while ($i <= ($half_actors - 1)) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$actor_list[$i].'</td></tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        while ($i <= $num_actors) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$actor_list[$i].'</td></tr>';
            $i++;
        }
    }
} 
echo "</table>";
?>
```